# NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 - Get Sales Team Name from Internal ID

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a suitescript which retrieves the Internal ID of a sales team (the one chosen in the Choose Team drop-down). I want to be able to display the name of the sales team.

So a simple question - given the Internal ID of a Sales Team, how can I retrieve its name?

Client script, 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getText instead of getValue:

```
currentRecord.getText({
    fieldId: 'salesgroup'
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But the docco for it is awful.